# How can I access MAMP Pro sites through Adobe Edge Inspect without using my IP address?

Tags: hosting, ip-address, mamp, adobe-edge-inspect

When I develop a website I typically use Edge Inspect in parallel with my computer's browser for testing. For every website, I create a new host in MAMP Pro, and create new directory on my computer which I point MAMP Pro to and put all my website files in. This way, I go to something like http://test.example/ and can access the developing site.

The problem comes in with Adobe Edge Inspect which cannot access the locally created hosts. I have found that if I point `localhost`, in MAMP Pro, to the directory of the site that I am working on, that I can then use my computer's IP address to have the results mirrored on my mobile device. The biggest problem is I have to make database changes (Magento, Wordpress, etc.) every time the IP address changes (which can happen frequently due to moving my laptop around and connecting to the internet in a variety of ways). Using `localhost` (my computer's IP) also eliminates one of the benefits of MAMP Pro.

The way I currently do it (based off of Andy Howells suggestion [over here](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/developers/tooling-and-workflow/)) is to use an alias in MAMP Pro so that I go to test.example.[my.ip.address].[xip.io](http://xip.io/). After that I must change the URL by opening PHPMyAdmin from MAMP Pro and changing the URL values for the site (again, typically Magento, or Wordpress). This then allows me to maintain one of the benefits of MAMP Pro by keeping my vhosts seperate, but I still must perform a database change every time I change IP addresses (as well as create a new alias most instances).

How can I use Adobe Edge Inspect with MAMP Pro and *not* change my IP address in the database?

[image: MAMP Pro config]

*(I don't use dyndns.com - they are just on from when I turned them on to test something earlier.)*